# Mechanical properties and nanocoatings

Tags: material-science

How do you model the changes in the mechanical properties of materials coated in with nano-materials? If I coat abs plastic with amorphous diamond how does that change the sheer, tensile and other strengths of the object?

Comment: It depends. More precisely than 'nano', roughly how thick are the coatings that you're interested in?

Comment: Hmm just kind of a general question but lets assume about 4-6 nm.

Comment: That's an awkward number in terms of modelling. Could you also clarify the actual properties you're interested in computing? E.g. the linear elasticity tensor? Floris's answer seems to address *hardness* more so than *strength*...

Comment: This question all came from the fact that I was wondering. I can take ABS plastic and change its load bearing characteristics by changing the geometry of how its printed but how can I make it other properties stronger so it can replace other materials. Can I take a steel valve and use a combination of printing geometry and Nano coatings and replace it with an ABS equivalent part.

Answer (score 0):

Diamond like coatings have been used for a long time to improve wear characteristics of materials. The important thing to note is that most of the time, "wear" happens because some local force exceeds the material's intrinsic strength. A coating can act to spread out the force so that there is no local stress concentration - think of it as making "a sharp point a little bit blunter".

Now in the case of very thin coatings (you stated 4 - 6 nm) you will see *some* benefit, but it will be small. Sometimes, the more significant advantage is the reduction of friction (see for example [this article](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/366526/)). A nice treatment is given [in this paper](http://www.miics.net/archive/getfile.php?file=68).

There is no simple answer...